Recover team account members
I changed the account owners from the inspector, and it turns out that I lost the team members of all accounts. Is there any way to recover that information? In this article: Account Team Member lost when Account Owner changes, it indicates that I could only recover it if I had done the process from the developer console or workbench. As I mentioned before, that was not the case. Can it be resolved in some way? Thanks, regards!

Note that those solutions allow you to keep the team members, not later recover them after they've been deleted. At this point, you'll need a backup if you want to recover your data. Salesforce Inspector doesn't support the KeepTeamMembers option, it looks like, so you'll probably want to log an issue about supporting this in the future. As always, with any ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) tool, make sure you make backups before modifying data. It is often the case that undoing is a lot harder than doing.
